# API Platform - External values Swagger are not showing in UI Openapis

Tags: symfony, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, api-platform.com

According to
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/#external

I have:

```
# config/api_platform/resources.yaml
App\Entity\Example:
...
  responses:
    '201':
      content:
        application/json:
          examples: 
            ExampleA:
              externalValue: 'https://127.0.0.1:8000/example/ExampleA.json'
            ExampleB:
              value:
                name: Nino
```

ExampleB is rendered.
[image]

But ExampleA with externalValue is not generated.
[image]

Comment: Please, use the answer section to answer your own question. With over 5 years of membership you should know how to use SO ;)

Comment: Excuse me @gp_sflover, In my experience, I have always seen in the same post how problems were solved, thx for the info

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to help, anyway only few people do it, and maybe because they never read SO guidelines (available in the Help Section) and because many have these habit used in classic Forums, but SO is not a Forum, it is a question/answer website (mainly for specific code-based questions) and that is why there is an "Answer" section, in which for sure you have already found many times useful answers for you in the last years :). Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. I found this, externalValue is not supported in Swagger-UI
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5433